# Cálculo con contador en un bucle

Tags: r, bucle-for, rstudio, while, contador

Estoy intentando calcular el número de agentes en función de algunos parámetros.
El código que os voy a adjuntar no da error pero no devuelve el valor correcto.
Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que mientras gos sea < que gos_target me vaya sumando 1 en el numero de agentes (agents = agents + 1). El valor de gos cambia en función del numero de agentes y por ello están las funciones "erlang" y "sl".
Necesito ayuda para poder realizar un contador correcto dentro del bucle para que me vaya sumando correctamente los agentes en función del gos (**en la función "resource"**)

El código es el siguiente:

```erlang
A <- ds$intensity
N <- ds$intensity+1
P <- A^(N)/factorial(N)
S <- N/(N-A)
X <- P*S            

Y <- 0
for (i in 1:A) {
    Y = Y + A^(i)/factorial(i) }

C <- X / (Y + X) }


sl <- function(agents, rate, duration, target) {      
                 A <- ds$intensity
                 pw <- erlang(A, N)
                 x <- (agents- A * (target / duration))
                 y <- pw * exp(-x)
                 1 - y }


resource <- function(agents, rate, duration, target, gos_target) {

N <- agents
gos <- ds$service_level
for (i in gos) {
while (i < (gos_target/100)) 
 { 
    agents <- agents+1
    if (agents > N) { gos <- sl(agents, rate, duration, target)
          i <- 1 +i }
  }}
return(agents)
    }
 
        

ds$agentes = resource(agents= ds$intensity+1 ,rate = ds$llamadas, duration = 180, target = 20, gos_target = 80)
```

Espero que podais ayudarme!! Gracias de antemano.
Saludos!!

Comment: En ningún lugar de `resource()` estás incrementando la variable `agents`, estás incrementando sobre la variable `i`, retorna eventualmente esta y no `agents`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Patricio!!

Answer (score -1):

Hay varios errores en el código que has proporcionado.

En primer lugar, en la función resource, el bucle for (i in gos) no está haciendo nada útil. Está iterando sobre cada elemento de gos, pero no está haciendo nada con cada elemento. Además, dentro del bucle for, estás usando una variable i que no está definida en ningún lugar.

En segundo lugar, dentro del bucle while, estás intentando aumentar el valor de agents en uno y luego verificar si agents es mayor que N. Sin embargo, en la primera línea de la función resource, estás asignando el valor de agents a N, lo que significa que siempre será cierto que agents es mayor que N, y el bucle se ejecutará infinitamente.

En tercer lugar, dentro del bucle while, estás asignando el resultado de la función sl a gos, lo que significa que gos ya no será una lista de valores, sino un único valor. Esto provocará que el bucle for se rompa, ya que ya no se puede iterar sobre un único valor.

En cuarto lugar, en la función sl, estás usando una variable A que no está definida en ningún lugar. Esta variable es necesaria para calcular el valor de pw.

Por último, en la función sl, estás utilizando la variable N, pero no estás asignando ningún valor a ella.

En resumen, hay varios errores en el código que has proporcionado. Para solucionar estos errores, deberás revisar el código cuidadosamente y corregir todas las referencias a variables no definidas, así como cualquier código que no esté haciendo lo que se supone que debe hacer. También deberás asegurarte de que todas las variables estén asignadas correctamente y que se estén utilizando correctamente en todo momento.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Peteco!! En principio, he corregido la mayoría de errores. Sin embargo, no comprendo bien lo del gos <- sl en la función resource. ¿Cómo puedo hacer entonces que el gos actualice su valor? Debe ser calculado de nuevo en función del nuevo número de agentes. Gracias!